# Why Schedulers.io() sometimes running in mainthread?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using RxAndroid instead of thread myself.
And I had subscribed it on io thread, but it sometimes running in main thread.
sometimes the log was print in main thread.

```
Observable.from(bitmaps.toArray(new Bitmap[0]))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .zipWith(Observable.range(0, bitmaps.size()), new Func2<Bitmap, Integer, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Bitmap bitmap, Integer i) {
                    Log.i("==", "" + i);
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .last()
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                }
            });
```

two thread in logcat:

```
04-28 14:33:14.696 7215-23795/  Thread: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
04-28 14:33:19.811 7215-7215/   Thread: main
```

Solution:
I move the subscribeOn() after zipWith() and it run ok.

```
Observable.from(bitmaps.toArray(new Bitmap[0]))
        .zipWith(Observable.range(0, bitmaps.size()), new Func2<Bitmap, Integer, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Bitmap bitmap, Integer i) {
                Log.i("==", "" + i);
                return true;
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .last()
        .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior.

Always remember this thumb rule,

> subscribeOn() always affects operators upstream to it and observerOn()
>   always affects operators downstream to it.

So when you move `subscribeOn()` below `zip()`, it makes the upstream run on `Schedulers.io()`.

You should also use observeOn() to observe the results on the main thread and make changes to the UI if required.

Answer (score 0):

.subscribeOn - where take answer
.observeOn -where carry

```
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: I move the subscribeOn after zipWith, It run ok.

Comment: @0Kai and remoowe  .observeOn ?